# How to delete rows by a condition using sqlalmchemy and fastapi?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to delete some rows that a 'null' in a Postgresql db by this:

```
async def delete_empty_batches():
    query = Batches.delete().where(Batches.c.acquired_by_warehouse_date is None)
    database.execute(query).fetchall()
    s = Batches.select()
    return await database.execute(s).fetchall()
```

But nothing happens. I have tried to make a query in pgAdmin and it worked but I can't get around with python.
I'm green when it comes to programming, how should I be going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the next code snippet:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, delete
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

async def delete_and_select_batches():
    async with database.transaction():
        # Delete rows with null values in acquired_by_warehouse_date column
        delete_query = delete(Batches).where(Batches.c.acquired_by_warehouse_date == None)
        await database.execute(delete_query)

        # Select remaining rows
        select_query = select([Batches])
        result = await database.execute(select_query)
        return result.fetchall()
```

Note: `==` is used instead of `is` in the `where` clause to compare values for equality.

Comment: I had slightly edited your code and it worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Snipped that worked

```
from sqlalchemy import select, delete
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

async def delete_and_select_batches():
    async with database.transaction():
        # Delete rows with null values in acquired_by_warehouse_date column
        delete_query = delete(Batches).where(Batches.c.acquired_by_warehouse_date == None)
        await database.execute(delete_query)

        # Select remaining rows
        select_query = select([Batches])
        return await database.execute(select_query)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).